# Excel Data Solutions

Tags: excel, solution

Here are my 2 columns:

```
| C      |   B    |
| 378    | 124.14 |
| 378    |   0.47 |
| 378    | 125.00 |
| Total  | 249.61 |
```

I would link Total data in another sheet but I could not find excel proper function.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to tell what your table looks like from what you've copied & pasted. Assuming it looks like this:

```
 +---+-------+-------+
 |   |   B   |   C   |
 +---+-------+-------+
 | 1 | 378   | 124.14|
 +---+-------+-------+
 | 2 | 378   |   0.47|
 +---+-------+-------+
 | 3 | 378   | 125   |
 +---+-------+-------+
 + 4 + TOTAL + 249.6 +
 +---+-------+-------+
```

The address of your total is C4.
Call this worksheet `Sheet1` and the file `File1.xls`.

To access cell C4 from another worksheet in the same file: `=Sheet1!C4`

To access cell C4 from another file: `=[File1.xls]Sheet1!$C$4`

Answer (score 1):

This might be over-simplifying, but you can just click the target cell, type `=` then click on the source sheet and click on the total.